Wix patch change registry value back to original value when that value is without change
Can anybody explain me this behavior?
Steps:

Install app created in Wix 4 with registry value XXX
Install patch A that changes registry value to YYY, works well
Install patch B that changes some other files but leave registry value without change, but after patch the registry value is changed back to XXX

If i change registry value in patch B (step 3) to ZZZ it again works well. I found workaround. I had to move component with that registry to separate Feature. Then it works without problem.
Wix code before workaround:
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui">
<Package        
        Name="App"      
        Language="1033"
        Version="2.0.0.8"
        Manufacturer="Develop"
        UpgradeCode="{E0EC963D-82A9-410E-93BA-11243A15E534}"
        InstallerVersion="500"
        ProductCode="{596EF69B-157C-4C02-A566-1ED06C68B67B}">
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />

<DirectoryRef Id="APPDIR">
 <Component Id="CMP_SetReg" Guid="{F0BD26A4-D356-4F17-BF60-4AC3EE7B820A}">      
  <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[ProductCode]" Action="write" Name="MyComments" Type="string" Value="XXX" KeyPath="yes"/>
 </Component>
 <Component Id="CMP_fileA" Guid="1307a453-6683-479f-a1be-f0fdc0d22cd5">
  <File Id="FILE_fileA" Source="$(var.Path)..\app.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
 </Component>      
 .
 .
</DirectoryRef>
<Feature Id="Main" Display="hidden" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="APPDIR" Title="Main program" >  
  <ComponentRef Id="CMP_SetReg" />
  <ComponentRef Id="CMP_fileA" />
  .
  .
</Feature>
<Feature Id="Optional" Level="1" Title="Services">
  <Feature Id="Service1" Level="1" Title="Service1" >
    <ComponentRef Id="..." />
  </Feature>
  .
  .
</Feature>
<CustomAction Id=...
.
.
</Package>
</Wix>

Patch code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
  <Patch
    AllowRemoval="yes"
    Classification="Update"    
    DisplayName=".."
    Manufacturer=".."
    MoreInfoURL="..">

    <Media Id="1000" Cabinet="MyPatch.cab">
      <PatchBaseline
        Id="MyPatch"
        BaselineFile="Setup.wixpdb"
        UpdateFile="SetupNew.wixpdb" />
    </Media>

    <PatchFamily
      Id="MyPatchFamily"
      Version="2.0.0.9"      
      Supersede="yes">      
      <ComponentRef Id="..." />
      .
      .
    </PatchFamily>
  </Patch>
</Wix>

Patching files works without problem, only registry patching has this weird behavior. I dont understand why.

My guess is that your patch B supersedes patch A so it removes patch A from the view during the patch application, reverting the value to what was in the MSI. PatchFamilies can only grow.

but why the value is not reverted if i move component with registry to separate feature?

Probably because you didn't include the separate feature in the list to be repaired, so it was ignored. Basically, you're breaking the rules of patching, so the behavior is getting less coherent. Patching can rapidly get non-trivial.

i know nothing about how to add or remove feature from list for repairing, i know only how to add components to patch.wxs (see my first post)

Patching in the Windows Installer is a very advanced topic. I really recommend understanding the ins and outs of the Windows Installer by reading all the MSDN content and experimenting with many different patching scenarios before shipping to production.

After change supersede value to "no" it works as expected. The weird thing is that only registry value was reverted to original value with supersede="yes". There are also many files (.dlls) whose version was increased in patch A and were unchanged in patch B but these files were not reverted (files are in the same feature as registry key).  But i agree that supersede="yes" was not correct because each patch does different changes

The Windows Installer works very hard to not downgrade files. You probably were seeing that behavior and possibly seeing side effects from that later.

According to Wix docs:

Supersede (YesNoTypeUnion) : Set this value to 'yes' to indicate that this patch will supersede all previous patches in this patch family. The default value is 'no'.

If you want patch B to supersede patch A, you need to change same registry value in patch B. Otherwise you should set supersede to no.
<PatchFamily
  Id="MyPatchFamily"
  Version="2.0.0.9"      
  Supersede="no">      
  <ComponentRef Id="..." />


i tried add to PatchFamily in Patch B  but it was same, if i changed value in newer MSI to ZZZ the value was changed to ZZZ in registry, if i left it to YYY the value was changed to XXX in registry
